# Count(id) и QueryBuilder в Kohana

Tags: kohana-3, mysql

При попытке выполнить запрос через `Query Builder` вылетает ошибка:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'COUNT(id)' in 'field list' [ SELECT `COUNT(id)` AS `check` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = 'admin' ]
```

То бишь count(id) он определяет как колонку по неизвестной мне причине.

Сама конструкция выглядит вот так:

```
DB::select(array('COUNT(id)', 'check'))
 ->from('users')
 ->where('login', '=', $login)
 ->execute()
 ->as_array();
```

В чем причина?

Comment: В том, что query builder экранирует все поступающие значения как названия полей, и такого поля нет (вот так я поработал переводчиком)

Для того, чтобы это заработало, `COUNT(id)` надо обернуть в `DB::expr()`
(так я поработал [читателем документации](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder#database-expressions))

Comment: @Etki там об этом ничего не сказано, и прекрасно виден пример, аналогичный пример в этой же

[документации][1].


  [1]: http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/database/query/builder#subqueries

Comment: Как не сказанно? Посмотрите мой ответ, там и ссылка на документацию.

Comment: @abibock_un увидел, но тогда уже совсем другой запрос.

Comment: @rnddev ну, еще один пункт за "не использовать кохану".

Comment: select(array('COUNT("id")', 'check'))
А так?

Comment: @Etki другого фреймворка с подобной структурой я не знаю.

Comment: codeigniter, yii?

Comment: @rnddev, я вообще его не знаю, но он вот он явно лежит в одной корзине с CodeIgniter и другими творениями, которые не смогли в определнный момент сделать скачок и вырасти в что-то серьезное и принять какие-то серьезные конвенции, продолжая делать вместо этого "как удобнее". Где-то посередине лежит Yii, который никак не может решить, в какую сторону он хочет, где-то повыше фалкон и ларавель (не трогал обоих), а единственный реально до безобразия приличный со всех сторон - это symfony, который похож на бочку, которую немедленно надо заполнить энтерпрайзом.

В общем более приличного выбора полно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что вы неправильно используете COUNT.
Вот пример из документации:

```
DB::select(array(DB::expr('COUNT(`username`)'), 'total_users'))->from('users')
```

[Docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder#database-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Напиши его без одинарных кавычек.

Comment: Если я так напишу, то php пошлет меня на половой орган с ошибкой синтаксиса (facepalm)